# Replacing all occurences of a specific word which are not enclosed with the words OPEN and CLOSE?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I have the following string:

> **OPEN** someone said hello **CLOSE** im saying hello people **OPEN** some said
>   hello **OPEN** they said hello again **CLOSE** i have to go now though **CLOSE** hello again!

I'm trying to match all occurences of **hello** (that are not enclosed in the **OPEN** and **CLOSE** words) and replace them with another word, possibly with a regex and PHP's `preg_replace` function (although I'm open to other methods as I can't think of any).

So from the above string the below will match (I've placed them in brackets with italics to help you distinguish):

> **OPEN** someone said hello **CLOSE** im saying (*hello*) people **OPEN** some said
>   hello **OPEN** they said hello again **CLOSE** i have to go now though **CLOSE**  (*hello*) again!

Not really sure how to go by doing this.

Edit perhaps this will clarify the nesting structure abit better:

```
OPEN
text
CLOSE

OPEN 
text
  OPEN
   text
  CLOSE
text
CLOSE
```

As you can see from above, the hello is not being notice because its within OPEN...CLOSE (so they are ignored) whereas the others which arent are going to be replaced.

Comment: If there were a 'hello' immediately before the last CLOSE in your example, would you want it matched or not?

Comment: Why is the one within `OPEN` `OPEN` not changed? If it's a mistake then I found a way to do this, if it's not I need to understand the reasoning to change my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alan's answer works great. However, since I already took the time to compose it, here is another way to do it using a callback function and the PHP `(?R)` recursive expression:

```php
function highlightNonNestedHello($str) {
    $re = '/# Two global alternatives. Either...
          (                          # $1: Non-O..C stuff.
            (?:                      # Step through non-O..C chars.
              (?!\b(?:OPEN|CLOSE)\b) # If not start of OPEN or CLOSE,
              .                      # then match next char.
            )+                       # One or more non-O..C chars.
          )                          # End $1:
        |                            # Or...
          (                          # $2: O..C stuff.
            \bOPEN\b                 # Open literal delimiter.
            (?R)+                    # Recurse overall regex.
            \bCLOSE\b                # Close literal delimiter.
          )                          # End $1:
    /sx';
    return preg_replace_callback($re, '_highlightNonNestedHello_cb', $str);
}
function _highlightNonNestedHello_cb($matches) {
    // Case 1: Non-O...C stuff. Highlight all "hello".
    if ($matches[1]) {
        return preg_replace('/\bhello\b/', '(HELLO)', $matches[1]);
    }
    // Case 2: O...C stuff. Preserve as-is.
    return $matches[2];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I numbered the `hello`s, so `hello2` and `hello5` are the ones that should get replaced.

```
$s0 = 'OPEN someone said hello1 CLOSE im saying hello2 people OPEN some said hello3 OPEN they said hello4 again CLOSE i have to go now though CLOSE hello5 again!';

$regex='~
hello\d
(?=
  (?:(?!OPEN|CLOSE).)*+
  (?:
    ( 
      OPEN
      (?:
        (?:(?!OPEN|CLOSE).)*+
        |
        (?1)
      )*
      CLOSE
    )
    (?:(?!OPEN|CLOSE).)*+
  )?
  $
)
~x';

$s1=preg_replace($regex, 'goodbye', $s0);
print($s1);
```

output:

```
OPEN someone said hello1 CLOSE im saying goodbye people OPEN some said hello3 OPEN they said hello4 again CLOSE i have to go now though CLOSE goodbye again!
```

**[demo](http://ideone.com/OQMYu)**

The lookahead uses the recursive subpattern construct, `(?1)` to try and match zero or more complete, nested `OPEN...CLOSE` structures between the currently-matched word and the end of the string.  Assuming all the `OPEN`s and `CLOSE`s are properly balanced, that means the `hello\d` it just matched is *not* inside such a structure.

Comment: I like yours better - it does not require using a callback function. +1

Answer (score 0):

Well this is my attempt, tell me if it works for you or not:

```
<?php

$str = 'OPEN someone said hello CLOSE im saying hello people OPEN some said hello OPEN they said hello again CLOSE i have to go now though CLOSE hello again!';
echo "<p>$str</p>"; //before

//first replace all of them
$str = str_replace('hello', '(hello)', $str);
//then replace back only those within OPEN CLOSE
function replace_back($match){return str_replace('(hello)', 'hello', $match[0]);}
$str = preg_replace_callback('/OPEN.*?\(hello\).*?CLOSE/', 'replace_back', $str); 

echo "<p>$str</p>"; //after

?>
<style>p{width:500px;background:#F1F1F1;padding:10px;font:13px Arial;}</style>
```