# I want to replace all occurences of a string which are not enclosed within < ... >

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to do server-side highlighting of searched words, by processing the output before sending it out.

The reasoning behind "server-side" is:

1) Javascript highlighting for unicode text sucks.
2) \b not working with unicode (at least in JS, AFAIK).
3) No lookbehind support in JS.

I was using the function below, but last night realized that the first part which was written to skip <...> is not working.

```
public function ss_highlight($terms, $buf)
{
    if (empty($terms))  {
        return $buf;;
    }

    /* sort before using length for better match */
    usort($terms, function($a, $b) {
        return mb_strlen($b) - mb_strlen($a);
    });
    $str_terms = implode('|', $terms);

    /* server side highlighter */
    $buf = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+>)*(?<=[\s|:|\-|>|\(|\)|\.|,|\/|^])('.$str_terms.')(?=[\s|:|\-|<|\(|\)|\.|,|\/]|$)/i', '$1<span class="highlight">$2</span>', $buf);

    return $buf;
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Regards.

PS: I saw some similar things in [Replacing all occurences of a specific word which are not enclosed with the words OPEN and CLOSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577470/replacing-all-occurences-of-a-specific-word-which-are-not-enclosed-with-the-word) but cannot figure out how to fit this to my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

DO NOT try to parse HTML with regular expressions!
Use a HTML Parser!

See [Highlight Search Terms in PHP without breaking anchor tags using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2292345/highlight-search-terms-in-php-without-breaking-anchor-tags-using-regex)  and [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to use DOMDocument to achieve this result. Still trying to understand how DOMDocument class work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, everybody knows using regex for HTML is a bad idea, but in this case, we really do not need the DOM, because we just want to replace some text aoccuring outside of any < ... >.

This solution seems to work fine for me:

```
public function ss_highlight($terms, $buf)
{
    if (empty($terms))  {
        return $buf;;
    }

    /* sort before using length for better match */
    usort($terms, function($a, $b) {
        return mb_strlen($b) - mb_strlen($a);
    });
    $str_terms = implode('|', $terms);

    /* server side highlighter */
    $buf = preg_replace_callback('#((?:(?!<[/a-z]).)*)([^>]*>|$)#si',
                        function ($matches) use ($str_terms) {
                            //return preg_replace('/(?<=[\s:\-\>\(\)\.,\/^])('.$str_terms.')(?=[\s:\-\<\(\)\.,\/]|$)/i', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $matches[1]).$matches[2];
                            return preg_replace('/(?<!\pL)('.$str_terms.')(?!\pL)/i', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $matches[1]).$matches[2];
                        }, $buf);

    return $buf;
}
```

Thanks to everybody.